# timestamp in milliseconds in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I need to measure two separate events in time and compare them (not in the same application), so I would like to know the timestamp from the same reference (different applications on the same machine).

What's the simplest way of doing this on a Windows system? I've read about gettimeofday but that seems to be a Unix-specific function.

Also I don't want to use boost or any other external library (windows libraries are fine).

Comment: Note you'll likely only be getting millisecond *precision*, not millisecond *accuracy*.

Comment: what's the difference there?

Comment: @TimothyShields: He said he has the same reference (same machine, different processes), so precision is the concern here.  That said, having a return value in units of milliseconds (or smaller) doesn't guarantee millisecond precision.

Comment: [Accuracy and precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) - read this.

Comment: More important is the difference between *precision* and *resolution*.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`GetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns a [`SYSTEMTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

[GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you a one millisecond timer. It's perfect for timestamps since you don't need to convert anything. Even timespans can be calculated within a 49,6 days period.

Comment: "The resolution of the GetTickCount function is limited to... the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds. "

Comment: @MooingDuck: Definitely something to be aware of, because it affects a LOT of time functions.